# Came across the word arity, and I am having a hard time understanding the context it is used in without knowing its definition

Tags: typescript, function, callback

I decided to hop onto the TS-Bandwagon, taking it upon myself to learn TypeScript. I rely heavily on the [TypeScript Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/), so understanding every word is imperative (obviously). A couple days ago I came across the word arity in the TS-docs, and I eventually just skipped the section because I didn't know what arity meant. For the most part I can usually rely on myself to eventually pickup the definition of a word from the context it is used in, however; I came across **arity** again today, and I am still not getting it. So I guess what I am asking is if someone can define *arity in a computer science context*_ for me?

---

###### Below is the part of the [TypeScript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#overloads-and-callbacks) containing the word 'arity' that I don't really understand, because I am not 100% certain that I know what arity means.

---

## Overloads and Callbacks #

##### ❌ Don’t write separate overloads that differ only on callback arity:

```
/* WRONG */
declare function beforeAll(action: () => void, timeout?: number): void;
declare function beforeAll(
  action: (done: DoneFn) => void,
  timeout?: number
): void;
```

##### ✅ Do write a single overload using the maximum arity:

```
/* OK */
declare function beforeAll(
  action: (done: DoneFn) => void,
  timeout?: number
): void;
```

❔ Why: It’s always legal for a callback to disregard a parameter, so there’s no need for the shorter overload. Providing a shorter callback first allows incorrectly-typed functions to be passed in because they match the first overload.

---

Comment: [arity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) is the number of arguments a function takes. `() => void` has an arity of 0. `(done: DoneFn) => void` has an arity of 1.

Comment: Awesome thanks bud, thats what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arity is the number of arguments taken by a function.

- The function : `action: () => void` has arity 0
- The function : `action: (done: DoneFn) => void` has arity 1

## More

Its a programming language concept (among other things): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity